# Late Binding Outlook.Folder

Tags: vba, excel, outlook, late-binding

I am having issues with the Microsoft Outlook Object Library, when working with two different Office versions (2007 and 2016).
I already found out that late binding is a solution here, but I don't know how to late bind other objects than Outlook.Application. Especially "Outlook.Folder" and "Outlook.Selection" is what I need for late binding.

I tried creating objects just like I did for my Outlook.Application called "appoutlook" but the code below keeps giving me the error message that the object creation via ActiveX components is not possible...

1st class:

```
Public Type Email_Attributes
 olApp As Object    
 olFolder As Object 
 olSelection As Object 
End Type
```

2nd class:

```
Dim olMail As Object
Dim appoutlook As Object
Set appoutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Const olMailItem As Long = 0
Set olMail = appoutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Dim strAttName As String

Dim new_mail As Email_Attributes

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set new_mail.olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set new_mail.olFolder = CreateObject("Outlook.Folder")
Set new_mail.olSelection = CreateObject("Outlook.Selection")
Set new_mail.olFolder = GetObject("ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder")
Set new_mail.olSelection = GetObject("ActiveExplorer.Selection")
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: `olFolder As Object` -> that's all there is to it: any call against `olFolder` will be resolved at run-time, i.e. "late-bound". `CreateObject` isn't the "late-binding" part, `As Object` is. Not all objects can be created. You can't `New` up a `Worksheet` in Excel, the object model has methods for that. Same with Outlook folders - you can't `New` them up, therefore you can't `CreateObject` them. Use the object model API for that. Work with early-bound code first, then redeclare everything `As Object`, done.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So I deleted the two lines where I use CreateObject for olFolder and olSelection. However, now I am still not able to use the ActiveExplorer.* commands. It says that the "ActiveExplorer" variable is unknown. How do I fix this?

Comment: You already have the Outlook App object created (`appoutlook`) so, `Set new_mail.olFolder = appoutlook.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder` - or, if you prefer, `Set new_mail.olFolder = new_mail.olApp.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder`, but I don't understand why you created a second instance of Outlook for `new_mail` when you already have `appoutlook`.  (Also, you can use `GetObject(, "OUTLOOK.Application")` to check if Outlook is already open...)

Comment: Using new_mail.olApp.ActiveExplorer.* fixed it. I also removed appoutlook from the code. Thanks a lot :)